# Invoking SMO via T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlclr, smo

I'd like to use SMO to do several things that aren't easily done in T-SQL. However, all the examples I've found are for C# or Powershell.  Is there an easy way to invoke SMO via T-SQL, as you could do with DMO and `sp_OACreate`?  One way around that would be to invoke the SMO via PowerShell via `xp_cmdshell` - but that's going to be ugly.  Suggestions?

The obvious example would be "script out a table using SMO", invoked via SQL.

Thanks.

Comment: What things are you trying to do, specifically? I bet they're probably as easily done in T-SQL as in SMO.

Comment: @siride While everything _can_ be done in straight T-SQL, scripting objects at least is a bit easier with SMO. Check out [Scripter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx) and [ScriptingOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.aspx).

Comment: @srutzky: I've used those and they're (mostly) great. I wonder, though, if you should just write a C# tool to do this? Any reason why it must be done through T-SQL?

Comment: @siride Agreed, that is certainly a good / valid question.

Comment: @srutzky what would be the advantage of this over a PowerShell script? I'd have to invoke both outside the SQL Server engine.  Was trying to do it through T-SQL since I'd already been doing it it that way via DMO.  Granted, 5-year-old question, but I wound up doing it through PowerShell.

Comment: @mbourgon Understood and fair enough. Not sure how large the PowerShell interpreter is and how long it takes to load into memory or if it needs to be loaded each time a PowerShell script is used. Maybe C# would be slightly more efficient if called many times? But PowerShell would likely be easier to change without having to compile anything. But yes, either way you are making an external call.

Comment: @srutzky fortunately for me, even dozens of calls are lightweight enough it's not a problem.  Thanks for the help and the suggestion on changing the answer.

Comment: Yer quite welcome. And good to know that calling PowerShell on a moderately-frequent basis is not an issue / noticeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, SMO is not directly invoke-able via SQLCLR. Not only is it -- [Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.aspx) -- not in the [Supported .NET Framework Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx) list, but it is specifically disallowed.

If you try to manually import that DLL via `CREATE ASSEMBLY`, you get the following error:

```sql
CREATE ASSEMBLY [SMO]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM
N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

Returns:

> Msg 6596, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo' is a system assembly. Consider creating a user assembly to wrap desired functionality.

Ok, so try "creating a user assembly to wrap desired functionality".

If your Assembly is marked with `PERMISSION_SET = SAFE` you get:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "SmoTest":
>   System.Security.SecurityException: **That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.**

If your Assembly is marked with `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE` you get:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "SmoTest":
>   System.Exception: **This functionality is disabled in the SQLCLR. It is recommended that you execute from your client application.**
>   System.Exception:
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager..ctor()
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server..ctor()

**UPDATE:**

And, I just found this related thread from January 2007 on the MSDN forums:

['microsoft.sqlserver.batchparser' is malformed or not a pure .NET assembly.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85fe8eb8-32a5-4c8f-be75-a5fb7d10d1d4/microsoftsqlserverbatchparser-is-malformed-or-not-a-pure-net-assembly?forum=sqlsmoanddmo)

Comment: Did you try decompiling the assemblies, recompiling in VS into a new set of assemblies and then running that via SQLCLR? I just don't think you went far enough.

Comment: @siride Ok, so I did just try (a little) and got the source via [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) but just do not have the time to update all of the Namespace references and/or whatever else is needed. Oh well, maybe if  you have time to try? ;-)